# stack with static abilities and when does a card go to the graveyard

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have been reading up on the stack and how it works, which confuses me even more in certain situations.

1) I have [Sigil Captain](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSigil%20Captain%5d)
 on the battlefield. My opponent has [Engineered Plague](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEngineered%20Plague%5d) with soldier as the chosen creature type. Now I summon a [Kor Duelist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKor%20Duelist%5d). What happens? What is the sequence of triggers? Does it die on entering the battlefield, does it get the +1/+1 counters?

2) I have Sigil Captain and [Veteran Armorsmith](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVeteran%20Armorsmith%5d) on the battlefield. Again I summon a Kor Duelist. I would guess it becomes a 1/1 with 2 +1/+1 counters and then again a +0/+1 from the Veteran Armorsmith but is this correct?

3) I have 2 Sigil Captains out, again I summon a Kor Duelist. Does it trigger 2 times resulting in a +5/+5? Because it is still a 1/1 creature even though it has +1/+1 counters on it from the first Sigil Captain.

4) Now I have a [Spellheart Chimera](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpellheart%20Chimera%5d) that is attacking (3 instants in graveyard, so a 3/3). We go into the declare blockers step and my opponent blocks with an [Angel of Light](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAngel%20of%20Light%5d). I [Lightning Bolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLightning%20Bolt%5d) it. It resolves, kills the angel and then goes into the graveyard? resulting in 4 instants in the graveyard in the combat damage step. Making my Spellheart Chimera a 4/3 that deals 4 trample damage to my opponent. Or does the lightning bolt go to the graveyard at the end of combat?

I get the stack and the flow of it, but it is kinda confusing with static abilities from creatures or artifacts.

Comment: Please limit the scope of your question to a single question.  Notably the situations with the sigil captains are similar enough to be in the same question, but the Chimera is a completely different thing.

Answer (score 2):

Static abilities operate continuously.<sup>[CR 604.1]</sup> The -1/-1 from [Engineered Plague](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEngineered%20Plague%5d) and the +0/+1 from [Veteran Armorsmith](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVeteran%20Armorsmith%5d) apply as soon as the [Kor Duelist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKor%20Duelist%5d) enters the battlefield. There is no moment when they don't apply.

[Sigil Captain](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSigil%20Captain%5d)'s triggered ability contains an *intervening “if” clause*. A triggered ability with a false intervening “if” clause when it would trigger doesn't trigger.<sup>[CR 603.4]</sup> A triggered ability with a false intervening “if” clause when it would resolves is removed from the stack instead.<sup>[CR 608.2]</sup>

In (1), the Sigil Captain's triggered ability doesn't trigger because the Kor enters as a 0/0.

In (2), the Sigil Captain's triggered ability doesn't trigger because the Kor enters as a 1/2.

In (3), the triggered ability of both Sigil Captains trigger and are added to the stack (in the order of your choice). When the one added second resolves, it grants two +1/+1 counters to the Kor Duelist. When the one added first would resolve, it's simply removed from the stack instead since the Kor Duelist is currently 3/3.

---

Spells are moved from the stack to the graveyard (Sorceries and Instants)<sup>[CR 608.2k]</sup> or the battlefield (others)<sup>[CR 608.3]</sup> as they finish resolving.

In (4), the the [Spellheart Chimera](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpellheart%20Chimera%5d) becomes a 4/3 as soon the Lightning Bolt finishes resolving, so it deals 4 trample damage .

Answer (score 1):

A kind soul answered them on another board. Thought I post his answer here aswell.

1) The Kor enters as a 0/0. It dies. It was never a 1/1. The Captain does not trigger.

2) The Kor enters as a 1/2. Again, it was never a 1/1. The Captain does not trigger.

3) The Kor (FINALLY) enters as a 1/1. The two Captains trigger.
The first Captain trigger to resolve gives the Kor two +1/+1 counters. It's NOW a 3/3.
The second Captain trigger fails to do anything. Since the Kor is currently a 3/3 and not a 1/1.

4) The Chimera currently has a Power of 4. It has Trample. It will assign/deal 4 damage to the Defending Player.